# What is this plant with long leaves growing tough green stalks?

Tags: identification

I brought this plant a while back, but I lost the name tag. It's supposed to grow well in less lighted areas, and it's supposed to generate lots of oxygen. 
Recently, after moving it in a new pot, it started growing large stalks which seem to be tough as wood.

[image: branches]
[image: entire plant]

Comment: This is a [spider plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophytum_comosum), the dark green variety. The long stalk will probably flower soon and/or grow baby plants. We *do* have a few questions about spider plants already, so I have to VTC, sorry. See [this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7076/what-plant-is-this-and-what-do-i-do-with-it) for example.

Comment: Thanks!  @Stephie, no worries, from what I read it's expected that identification questions to have duplicates, since it's hard to search for. Anyways, I got my answer.